# IJCADの.Netでアクティブウィンドウにフォーカスをセットできない

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD 2015で.Netを使った開発をしています。

フォーカスをアクティブなドキュメントにセットしたいのですが、それらしいメソッドが見当たりません。
AutoCAD 2014ではDocument.Window.Focus()で実現できるのですが、IJCADには用意されていないのでしょうか？

他に方法があれば教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

IJCAD 2015にはDocument.Window.Focus()メソッドが実装されていません。ただし、MFCを使えば対処できます。

Private Declare Function SetFocus Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr

と宣言したのち

SetFocus(Doc.Window.Handle)

のように呼び出せばアクティブなドキュメントにフォーカスを移動できます。

IJCAD 2016以降であればFocusメソッドが実装されているので、doc.Window.Focus()によるフォーカス設定が可能です。